# LightGBM Check failed: (feature_fraction) <= (1.0) when using RandomizedSearchCV for a uniform distribution between 0.5 and 0.95

Tags: scikit-learn, scipy, grid-search, lightgbm

I do get the following error when running LGBMRegressor through sklearns RandomizedSearchCV and GridSearchCV:

```
lightgbm.basic.LightGBMError: Check failed: (feature_fraction) <= (1.0) at /__w/1/s/python-package/compile/src/io/config_auto.cpp, line 363 .
```

I am quite baffled by it because I input the parameters under the following distributions:

```
from scipy.stats import uniform
params = dict()
params['feature_fraction'] = uniform(0.5, 0.95)
params['bagging_fraction'] = uniform(0.35, 0.95)
params['bagging_freq'] = [1]
```

So I probably don't see it, but shouldn't `uniform(0.5, 0.95)` not be able to return a value greater than 1?

From the documentation at [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.uniform.html) (which is a little unclear to me) I thought for a second 0.5 is the mean as loc usually refers to it. But in the uniform distributions case it's just the left hand side.

I am grateful if you could point out to me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: From your linked docs pages, the second parameter `scale` is not the right side of the interval, it is the width.

Comment: @BenReiniger Yikes! You are right! thanks, what a blunder! Believe it or not, I didn't see this for the past two days!